# Understanding Google Code Jam 2013 - X Marks the Spot

Tags: binary-search

I was trying to solve Google Code Jam problems and there is one of them that I don't understand. Here is the question (World Finals 2013 - problem C): https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/2437491/dashboard#s=p2&a=2

And here follows the problem analysis: https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/2437491/dashboard#s=a&a=2

I don't understand why we can use binary search. In order to use binary search the elements have to be sorted. In order words: for a given element e, we can't have any element less than e at its right side. But that is not the case in this problem. Let me give you an example:

Suppose we do what the analysis tells us to do: we start with a left bound angle of 90° and a right bound angle of 0°. Our first search will be at angle of 45°. Suppose we find that, for this angle, X < N. In this case, the analysis tells us to make our left bound 45°. At this point, we can have discarded a viable solution (at, let's say, 75°) and at the same time there can be no more solutions between 0° and 45°, leading us to say that there's no solution (wrongly).

I don't think Google's solution is wrong =P. But I can't figure out why we can use a binary search in this case. Anyone knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand why we can use binary search. In order to use
>   binary search the elements have to be sorted. In order words: for a
>   given element e, we can't have any element less than e at its right
>   side. But that is not the case in this problem.

A binary search works in this case because:

- the values vary by at most 1
- we only need to find one solution, not all of them
- the first and last value straddle the desired value (X .. N .. 2N-X)

I don't quite follow your counter-example, but here's an example of a binary search on a   sequence with the above constraints. Looking for 3:

```
1 2 1 1 2 3 2 3 4 5 4 4 3 3 4 5 4 4
[                                 ]
[               ]
        [       ]
            [   ]
              *
```

Comment: What if the list is: 4 3 2 3 4 5 6 5 4?
Or even worse: 6 5 4 3 4 3 4 5 6?
In both cases you tend to think that the list doesn't contain the number 3. Or at least you have to search in both sides. But in the last case, it will be O(n) instead of O(log n).

Comment: You're right. There is a third constraint that the desired value must be between the first and last value. That's satisfied in the problem since the ends are `X` and `2N-X` when searching for N.

Comment: @GutoMarraraMarzagao I updated the answer to address the error you found.

Answer (score 0):

I have read the problem and in the meantime thought about the solution. When I read the solution I have seen that they have mostly done the same as I would have, however, I did not thought about some minor optimizations they were using, as I was still digesting the task.

Solution:

Step1: They choose a median so that each of the line splits the set into half, therefore there will be two provinces having `x` mines, while the other two provinces will have N - `x` mines, respectively, because the two lines each split the set into half and

```
2 * x + 2 * (2 * N - x) = 2 * x + 4 * N - 2 * x = 4 * N.
```

If `x = N`, then we were lucky and accidentally found a solution.

Step2: They are taking advantage of the "fact" that no three lines are collinear. I believe they are wrong, as the task did not tell us this is the case and they have taken advantage of this "fact", because they assumed that the task is solvable, however, in the task they were clearly asking us to tell them if the task is impossible with the current input. I believe this part is smelly. However, the task is not necessarily solvable, not to mention the fact that there might be a solution even for the case when three mines are collinear.

> Thus, somewhere in between X had to be exactly equal to N!

Not true either, as they have stated in the task that

> You should output IMPOSSIBLE instead if there is no good placement of
>   borders.

Step 3: They are still using the "fact" described as un-true in the previous step.

---

So let us close the book and think ourselves. Their solution is not bad, but they assume something which is not necessarily true. I believe them that all their inputs contained mines corresponding to their assumption, but this is not necessarily the case, as the task did not clearly state this and I can easily create a solvable input having three collinear mines.

Their idea for median choice is correct, so we must follow this procedure, the problem gets more complicated if we do not do this step. Now, we could search for a solution by modifying the angle until we find a solution or reach the border of the period (this was my idea initially). However, we know which provinces have too much mines and which provinces do not have enough mines. Also, we know that the period is `pi/2` or, in other terms `90 degrees`, because if we move `alpha` by `pi/2` into either positive (counter-clockwise) or negative (clockwise) direction, then we have the same problem, but each child gets a different province, which is irrelevant from our point of view, they will still be rivals, I guess, but this does not concern us.

Now, we try and see what happens if we rotate the lines by `pi/4`. We will see that some mines might have changed borders. We have either not reached a solution yet, or have gone too far and poor provinces became rich and rich provinces became poor. In either case we know in which half the solution should be, so we rotate back/forward by `pi/8`. Then, with the same logic, by `pi/16`, until we have found a solution or there is no solution.

Back to the question, we cannot arrive into the situation described by you, because if there was a valid solution at `75 degrees`, then we would see that we have not rotated the lines enough by rotating only `45 degrees`, because then based on the number of mines which have changed borders we would be able to determine the right angle-interval. Remember, that we have two rich provinces and two poor provinces. Each rich provinces have two poor bordering provinces and vice-versa. So, the poor provinces should gain mines and the rich provinces should lose mines. If, when rotating by `45 degrees` we see that the poor provinces did not get enough mines, then we will choose to rotate more until we see they have gained enough mines. If they have gained too many mines, then we change direction.

Comment: The problem tells that "No three gold mines are co-linear". It's written at "Input" section. But in fact it's not true that "somewhere in between X had to be exactly equal to N!". Anyway, imagine that you measure a rich province at angle 0. Then you rotated the lines by pi / 4 and checked that this province is still rich. What I'm telling is that, even in this case, you can have many angles BETWEEN 0 and pi / 4 where X = N. In order words: suppose that I told you that a given province is rich at 2 different angles. Even then you can't tell me what happens between those angles.

Comment: And let me explain my point. The standard implementation of binary search tell us: look at the middle element. If the element you're looking for is bigger, than search at its right side. Otherwise, search at its left side. Ok, we are searching between angles 0 and 90. So the first angle we will check is 45, as it's the middle between the bounds. Now we check that, at 45°, a given province is rich. Then we fall in the same case as before. We can't tell with this information for which side we have to rotate. But the solution says that we can! I don't understand why.

Comment: In your solution you take a province and compare its mines in 2 different angles to check which direction you're going to rotate next. But the standard binary search doesn't make us to check 2 different elements in order to tell us where to go. That is, the solution provided is different than yours. In fact, the solution says: "So we pick an angle [..] and check how big is X. [..] If it's smaller, we rotate to the right. Otherwise, to the left." (I've changed some words to fit here). But imagine that at 75° you have X=N and at 45° X<N. If your first angle is 45°, you'll go right wrongly.

Comment: Nope, when you have rotated it with 45 degree you can see whether the poor provinces are still poor. If so, then you did not rotate it enough and you have to search in the second half of the interval. If not, then you have to search in the first interval. I am not comparing the two inner angles in this step, I am just checking whether I have rotated too much, not enough or a solution was found. And then we go to the next step, as we have reduced the search-space to half.

Comment: But to know whether the province is STILL poor, you have to know if the province WAS poor last time. Because if not, the province at 45° will be just poor, not STILL poor. But it's not important for my doubt.
Ok, let me show an example of what I'm telling you. Suppose you have the following points: http://ctrlv.in/329996. Note that the province at the first quarter is poor. Then imagine you rotate the lines 45°. Then you'll have: http://ctrlv.in/329997. Note that the first province is still poor. But also note that, between the 2 angles (0° and 45°) there's a solution: http://ctrlv.in/329998.

Comment: Why skipping this solution isn't dangerous? In this example, luckly if you continues rotating counter-clockwise you still find a solution. But will it always be true? What if the skipped solution was the only solution at all?

Comment: In your example it is not still poor, as it is poor again. I understand now your problem. Naturally, you need to keep track of the mines. Note, that after rotating by 45 degrees the provinces contain the same number of mines, but they contain different mines than before. I believe your point is valid, but under "still poor" we should think for the case when they have not gained enough mines and exclude the case when they have gained and lost mines. Also, we should modify this binary search algorithm so that we do not always choose a single angle-interval, only in the case when we know for sure

Comment: that a given angle-interval cannot possibly be the solution.

Comment: But if we have to keep track which mines was in a given province, then our comparison won't be O(1) anymore, as we'd have to compare all mines in this province with the previous mines. The worst case will be O(n/4). And choosing both interval also will make the algorithm slower. I think this is not what they meant. In fact, they tell that each iteration takes O(n), which give us a total running time of O(40n), as they prove the maximum number of iterations is 40.